# Create wordpress mata_value for image

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to create meta_value for image, located in wordpress database table name `postmeta` having `meta_key` = `_wp_attachment_metadata`.

For every image wordpress create `_wp_attachment_metadata` something like `a:5:{s:5:"width";i:657;s:6.....}`

Can any one tell me how to create this `meta_value`.

Comment: You have metadata for image and, you want to save them for specific images?

Comment: Can you post your sample image data that you are asking to update in meta ???